# Can I create a WPF custom controll that has a "placeholder" item?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

We have a lot of controls that consist of: A container with rounded borders and a couple of buttons that call save & cancel commands on the view model somthing like this:

```
     <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="1" Padding="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
           <!--Some Control Stuff Here...-->

          <controls:SaveCancelButtons/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

What I'd like to do is make a custom control/style/template etc that allows me to reuse this so I can just wrap any new user control in a set of tags that places its content into the stack panel (where the comment is above)

What's the best way of achiving this?

**EDIT:**

OK Now I have a template like so:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundedBordersTemplate">
    <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="1" Padding="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter/>

            <controls:SaveCancelButtons/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the control is implimented like so:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource RoundedBordersTemplate}">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Description: " Width="72"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                        Width="205" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Type:" Width="72" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TypeList}" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                          SelectedValuePath="ID"
                          Width="205" />
                </StackPanel>                
            </StackPanel>            
        </ContentControl>
```

But I only see the Save/Cancel buttons.

Comment: The code in your second example works fine for me.  The only difference is that I am not using your custom `SaveCancelButtons` - can you try replacing them with a regular `Button` in the template to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Damn :¬( I've put that xaml, and only that xaml, in to Kaxaml (just to make sure nothing in my current project is contaminating the styles/templates) and I get the same results I got before...Hmm I'll have to experiment.

Comment: Ooops I misses the "TargetType" :¬) all sorted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a `ControlTemplate` for type `ContentControl`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundedBordersTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="1" Padding="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentPresenter />
                <controls:SaveCancelButtons/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Then use it as below:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource RoundedBordersTemplate}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>Hello</Button>
            <Button>World</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>
```

To give you:

[image: Example]

**Update:** this has the advantage of not requiring you to subclass ContentControl for a View-only change

Comment: Thanks ... This looks exaclty like what I'm after although I can only see my save/cancel buttons. I cant seem to see the content (what would be the hello & world buttons in your example)

Comment: Without knowing details of the rest of your application it will be difficult to diagnose - it could be caused by a number of things.  As a diagnostic step, can you see the content if you add them to the template instead of to the `ContentControl`?

Comment: Thanks Steve, Yes I can see them if i add them to the template

Comment: I think I'll need to see some sample code for this!  Can you either add some to the current question or ask another?

Answer (score 1):

Your control should inherit from ContentControl (Control that contains CONTENT - i.e. other controls). Like all proper WPF controls this control is TOTALLY INVISIBLE - and the other stuff (buttons visual appearance) is added via the templating / styling mechanism.

Your subclass of ContentControl is then responsible for actually providing the logic for the buttons.